# Alternative values for the constant in the cosmological equation of state? (Mislaid list)

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

A couple of days ago I came across - but now cannot locate - an online list of about eight or nine alternative theoretical values for the constant in the [cosmological equation of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state_(cosmology)) (W = 1, -1/3, 0, etc), with their likely physical interpretations, all in a short table within some text (with "W" showing in uppercase W rather than the usual lowercase w").

I've searched StackExchange, Wikipedia, via Google, Google Scholar, even Quora  and my own search history - nada. (Also Dodelson.)

Does it ring a bell with anyone, please?